# Javascript menu - copy javascript thumb gallery into each area doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, gallery

I got a small problem with my webpage.
http://sabinequardon.dk/Portfolio/#portfolio

When you click on "photography" the gallery shows just fine,
but then when you click on "photoshop" something's wrong.

I've copied the exact same code into the photoshop-section, and used javascript fadeIn & fadeOut to show the dif. content, but it doesn't work.

Javascript here: http://sabinequardon.dk/Portfolio/assets/js/gallery.js

Do i really have to give it different names/classes, and make both css and javascript several times to make it work?

I tried everything, just can't seem to find the mistake.

Thanks!
- Sabine

Comment: I would recommend for you to learn javascript, because you have never done that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This plugin is not written to be used in the way, that it can be reused for multiple galleries on one page, and it would need some massive work to enable this functionality for it.

Quickiest and easiest call for you would be just separat Photography and Photoshop into differeent html documents, so the ids will not colide

Best wishes

Marian

Comment: I figured out myself how to do it.. 
gave it diff. names and classes, and it worked. a lot of work but what the hell :-)